# Assign value to variable in Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to write a postman collection test and I'm struck at a point where I need to assign a value to global variable and use it in another api call.

Here it goes:
The api response is like this:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "code": 200,
    "data": {
        "expires_time": 10800,
        "authentication_token": "access-token",
        "refresh_token": "refresh-token"
    }
}
```

The test I'm writing is something like this:

```
tests["Status code is 200"] = responseCode.code === 200;

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("Authorization", jsonData.data.authentication_token);
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are saying that you need to assign global variable while your code is trying to assign environment variable, which is different.

Assigning global variable looks like following:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

Make sure to create global variable with empty value in the Postman UI first, and than you will be able to assign value to it using above piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I figured out how it is done. It's same as setEnvironmentVariable but the scope will change for Global and Environment vars. What I was doing was I was not saving once I write the test :| mY bad. Thanks.